# Can you use multiple try catch?

Tags: php

hello i just want to ask if i can use multiple `try catch` on my `php` script without negative out come? i'm currently tasked to maintain a web app, however it was written in POP, so would this result to issues if i do this multiple times? I'm new to my job and i don't wanna loose it please help.

```
    try{
        mysqli_autocommit($conn,FALSE);
        mysqli_autocommit($conn2,FALSE);
        mysqli_autocommit($conn3,FALSE);

        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE table SET field='$variable' WHERE field='$varable2'");

        // Commit transaction
        mysqli_commit($conn);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        write_mysql_log("Error: $error", $conn3);

        // Rollback transaction
        mysqli_rollback($conn);
        mysqli_rollback($conn2);
        mysqli_rollback($conn3);

        echo "<script>alert('***Process Failed***'); window.location = 'target_page.php';</script>";
    }

    //second try catch
    try{
        mysqli_autocommit($conn,FALSE);
        mysqli_autocommit($conn2,FALSE);
        mysqli_autocommit($conn3,FALSE);

        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE table SET field='$variable' WHERE field='$varable2'");

        // Commit transaction
        mysqli_commit($conn);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        write_mysql_log("Error: $error", $conn3);

        // Rollback transaction
        mysqli_rollback($conn);
        mysqli_rollback($conn2);
        mysqli_rollback($conn3);

        echo "<script>alert('***Process Failed***'); window.location = 'target_page.php';</script>";
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with multiple `try...catch...` blocks, but they would normally be a block which you want to process in one go.  It's not worth it if you are trying to do this for each statement and rolling back the one statement - more common if you are doing several SQL statements and you want to rollback all of the statements if anything fails.

Comment: Can you more describe your problem? It seems that you are using multiple try-catch

Comment: @NigelRen yes the code was actually written with POP with multiple separate files, any suggestion on how i can rollback all of statements just incase anything fails on all of the SQL statements scattered across this code base?

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong but not good to use multiple try catch.
Keep in mind that in one 'try' you can have multiple 'catch' depending on wich kind of exception was hapenning.

```
try {
   //Operations that are succeptible to throw ExceptionTypeOne or ExceptionTypeTwo
} catch (ExceptionTypeOne $exception) {
   //What to do if ExceptionTypeOne happen
} catch(ExceptionTypeTwo $exception) {
   //And if ExceptionTypeTwo happen
}
```

Comment: thanks, any suggestion on how i can rollback all of statements just incase anything fails on all of the SQL statements scattered across this code base?

Comment: You should use transaction to be able to rollback everything. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-transaction/

Comment: i tried using commit and rollback but @NigelRen was right to use mysqli_savepoint but i don't know how that works, can't even find documentation for it.